# How to match login credentials from API in Angular

Tags: angular

I am new in **Angular**. I have a login page and **api link**. I want the user credentials **match** with the credentials in API,

I have a form:

```
<form  class="content l1">
            <!-- login-detail -->
            <div class="login-detail l1">
                <h3>Log in</h3>
                <p>Log in using your registered account</p>
                <input type="text" #name class="box-align" placeholder="User name">
                <input type="password" #password class="box-align" placeholder="Password">
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember" class="remember"> <label for="checkbox">Remember Me</label>
                 <button class="btn-sub" value="Log in" (click)="CheckLogin(name.value,password.value)">Log in</button>
            </div>
            <!-- login-detail -->
        </form>
```

I have read post and get to know I need **Http and Obversable** method to get data and match, is that right?

Please **guide** me so I start API integration in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

For Log in I would prefer angular forms. what is the point of using a form but then binding elements by id.

```
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)" #form="ngForm">
            <!-- login-detail -->
            <div class="login-detail l1">
                <h3>Log in</h3>
                <p>Log in using your registered account</p>
                <input type="text"class="box-align" placeholder="User name" name="username" ngModel>
                <input type="password" class="box-align" placeholder="Password" name="password" ngModel>
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember" class="remember">
 <label for="checkbox" name="remember" ngModel>Remember Me</label>
                 <button class="btn-sub" value="Log in" type="submit")">Log in</button>
            </div>
            <!-- login-detail -->
        </form>
```

and then on the component

```
public onSubmit(options) {
        this.loginService.passwordFlow(options.username, options.password, ....);
      }
```

LoginService is a standard angular service that will handle you http request 
with a function similar to that

```
    public passwordFlow(username: string, password: string, remember: string) {
    this.httpClient.post(`http://blahblah/auth/login`, {
      remember,
      username,
      password
    }).toPromise().then((loginResponse}) => {
      // do something with response
      this.router.navigate(['/somewhere']);
    }, (error) => {
      // do something with error
    });
  }
```

Comment: where i give api URL and get response?

Comment: @kappo you need to create a service I'll add a sample

Comment: I have added HttpClientModule following this tutorial : 
  https://angular.io/guide/http    but it shows error in passwordFlow

Comment: Yeah I just named the function with a random logical name

Comment: can u make plunker of loginComponent?